# How to send nested array of object using formdata from react js and save in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

when i send array of object in json it work perfectly but it was not work using form data..
when isend this {"name":"arijit","age":"30","singerimg":null,"songs":[{"title":"abc","duration":"5"}]} it work perfectly but

```
var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', $('#name').val())
        formData.append('age', $('#age').val())
        formData.append('singerimg',  $('#image')[0].files[0]? ($('#image')[0].files[0]):(""))
        formData.append('songs[0][title]', 'abc')
        formData.append('songs[0][duration]', '50')
```

it's not work

## model.py

```
class singer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 25, null=True, blank = True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length = 4, null=True, blank = True)
    singerimg = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos", max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class songs(models.Model):
    singer = models.ForeignKey(singer,related_name = 'songs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 25, null=True, blank = True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length = 25, null=True, blank = True)
```

## serializers.py

```
class soSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = songs
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'duration']

class singerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    songs = soSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = singer
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'age','singerimg', 'songs']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        song = validated_data.pop('songs')
        
        sin = singer.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for song_data in song:
            songs.objects.create(singer=sin, **song_data)
        
        return sin
```

Comment: Hi Srikanta, could you please give more details on the error you're receiving? If the framework can't parse the request body you may want to check `rest_framework` configuration. You're interesting in `DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES` key of the `REST_FRAMEWORK` configuration, in     particular you need to make sure that the `rest_framework.parsers.FormParser` parser is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

when i send array of object in json it work perfectly but it was not work using form data.. when isend this {"name":"arijit","age":"30","singerimg":null,"songs":[{"title":"abc","duration":"5"}]} it work perfectly but

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).